# How to fetch Coredata List in IntentHandler class (WidgetKit-SwiftUI)?

Tags: swiftui, core-data, widgetkit

I am not able to fetch data in my `IntentHandler` class. My Goal is select Todo from the `CoreData` list and display it in Widget. [image]

I am trying to display a list from `CoreData` in Widget Intent and I am expecting to resolve this issue.

```
extension IntentHandler : ConfigurationIntentHandling {
    func provideTodoNameOptionsCollection(for intent: ConfigurationIntent, searchTerm: String?, with completion: @escaping (INObjectCollection<TodoData>?, Error?) -> Void) {
        var arrTodoData = [TodoData]()
        coreDH.getAllTodos().forEach { todos in
            let todoIntent = TodoData(identifier: todos.id?.uuidString, display: todos.name ?? "")
            arrTodoData.append(todoIntent)
        }
        let collection = INObjectCollection(items: arrTodoData)
        completion(collection, nil)
    }
}

class IntentHandler: INExtension{
    let coreDH = CoreDataHandler.shared
    override func handler(for intent: INIntent) -> Any {
        // This is the default implementation.  If you want different objects to handle different intents,
        // you can override this and return the handler you want for that particular intent.
        return self
    }
}
```

Comment: Please share your `IntentHandler` class code which you have done so far.

Comment: As per your requirement, I have sent the code of IntentHandler Class. But unfortunately, provideTodoNameOptionsCollection method is not called.

Comment: Make sure you are actually sharing the data via AppGroup or some other form. Without a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) it is impossible to help you troubleshoot.

Answer (score 1):

### If your IntentHandler doesn't get called:

- Ensure your Widget uses `IntentConfiguration` not `StaticConfiguration`
- Ensure your time line provider conforms to `IntentTimelineProvider`
- Run the app scheme, then run the intent scheme, you should be able to debug and breakpoints would work.
- [Widgets Code-along, part 3: Advancing timelines](https://developer.apple.com/wwdc20/10036) (5:31)
- [Add Configuration and Intelligence to Your Widgets](https://developer.apple.com/wwdc20/10194)

### If you need to share data between your app and extension:

- App's data is sandboxed and is not accessible by extension
- Configure App Groups and you could create core data file in the shared container to be able to access in your extension
- If App and Extension use exactly the same data you could use the same sqlite file in the shared container (both app and extension would have access to it)
- If App and Extension use different data and there is only a small portion that is common, then use History Tracking
- [Configuring App Groups](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/configuring-app-groups)
- [Consuming Relevant Store Changes](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/consuming_relevant_store_changes)

Comment: do you know how to debug functions in IntentHandler? I ran the app scheme, and then the intent scheme, I picked the main app to run and it just launches my app with siri. I need it to run when showing a list of widget configuration options (which it does run) but I just want to debug it. How?

Comment: Refer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74145087/1046037