# Why I am getting Replace "com.apple.springboard" when I want to run widget extension schema?

Tags: ios, xcode, widgetkit

Usually, to debug a share extension, I will run the schema as share extension, so that I can get all the print message in XCode console.

If I run the schema as main app, I will not able to get any output from share extension.

This is how it looks like, when I am debugging my share extension.

[image]

Now, I want to debug my widget extension.

I try the run schema as widget extension.

[image]

However, I am getting

```
Replace "com.apple.springboard"
```

message. When I click Replace and run, I am not getting any print output from widget extension.

May I know, how can I debug my widget extension properly? Thanks.

Comment: Check your scheme executable settings, it should be Ask On Launch, and also see this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64922585/xcode-ios-14-widgetkit-not-always-attached-to-debugger