# Complication blank when locked

Tags: apple-watch, watchos, widgetkit, apple-watch-complication

My apple watch complication (widgetKit) is blank when the watch is locked. Don't know where to search for the issue so I don't know what code to provide. Timeline Provider or SwiftUI View?

Comment: Is the timeline provider getting called? Add Logger and log and view in console. Are you using `.privacySensitive(true)`?

Comment: I am not using `.privacySensitive(true)`. Can I see the widget extension console outputs in the normal console?

Comment: Breakpoints will work Refer to https://stackoverflow.com/a/74145087/1046037 explains how to attach the debugger to the widget process. Keep in mind that widget runs as a separate process (even when the app is not open). For logging you need to use Logger and view logs in the Console app (not Xcode console), otherwise use breakpoints using the above link.